# Как получить одномерные срезы столбцов из 2d-массива (список списков)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, матрицы

Подскажите, можно ли из списка списков выбрать столбцы командой в 1 строчку?

Конечно можно сделать через `for`, например:

```
col0 = [obj[0] for obj in arr]
col1 = [obj[1] for obj in arr]
```

Но есть ли возможность сделать это как-нибудь через срезы, что-то типа `[:;0]`?

Опять же, если надо получить несколько столбцов, то как-то не очень красиво писать кучу строк по выборке нескольких столбцов или через `append` делать.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Вариант 1:** воспользуйтесь [zip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) для транспонирования матрицы:

```
l = [[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]

c1, c2, c3 = zip(*l)
```

результат:

```
In [87]: print(c1, c2, c3)
(0, 3, 6, 9) (1, 4, 7, 10) (2, 5, 8, 11)
```

---

**Вариант 2:** если хотите через срезы - можно использовать срезы в транспонированной матрице:

```
m = list(zip(*l))
c1, c2, c3 = m[0], m[1], m[2]
```

**Вариант 3:** или же используйте модуль Numpy, где все это и **многое** другое доступно "из коробки":

```
import numpy as np

In [98]: a = np.array(l)

In [99]: a
Out[99]:
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])

In [100]: a[:, 2]
Out[100]: array([ 2,  5,  8, 11])
```

Comment: Да, решение неплохое. На производительность, если мы не гигабайты данных обрабатываем можно забить, я правильно понимаю? На счет numpy - тут, как я понимаю и с производительностью все будет лучше, чем делать это на голом питоне?

Comment: @Zhihar, если речь о гигабайтах, то однозначно - Numpy / Pandas и в некоторых сложных случаях Numba

Comment: кстати если дополнительно требуется из str в int перевести - то как я понимаю тут что с Numpy, что без все равно через `list(map(int,...))` делать :(

Comment: @Zhihar, `a = np.array([['1', '2', '3'], ['4','5','6']]); b = a.astype("int16")` - этот способ работает если все элементы могут быть преобразованы в числа. ;) Если не поможет Numpy, то скорее всего поможет Pandas.

Comment: @Zhihar, я ради интереса замерил - у меня вышло, что на матрицах меньше 18х18 numpy медленнее чем `list(zip(*arr))[x:y]` или `[(obj[i] for obj in arr) for i in range(x,y)]`. Ну и `zip` чуть быстрее чем `list comprehension`.